# Access/modify specific row/column of text file

Tags: c++, string, text, edit, fstream

I'm doing some practice in understanding how fstream works, and I've hit a brick wall.

I've initialised a 3x3 text file with each element being 'temp'

I want to be able to access a specific "element", delete it, and then replace it with a string (could be larger or smaller than the current size) but enclosed by the tab characters.

i.e. simulating an edit of a text file

I've been doing some research online, like here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/ but I struggle a lot with implementing it myself.

So the text file, "example.txt" contains:

```
temp    temp    temp    
temp    temp    temp    
temp    temp    temp
```

I'd like to open it for writing, seek the position of say, row 2, column 2 (i.e. corresponding to \n and \t characters), replace it with another string, for example "thisisareplacement"

```
temp    temp    temp    
temp    thisisareplacement  temp    
temp    temp    temp
```

From my understanding, this may not be possible as I'm inputting a much larger size of characters. However I believe somehow defining these \n and \t characters to enclose my strings could give me an opportunity.

Here's my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

    int main () {

    int numRows = 3;

      ofstream myfile ("example.txt");
      if (myfile.is_open())
      {
        for (int i = 0; i < numRows; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < numRows; j++) {
            myfile << "temp\t";
            } 
        myfile << "\n";
        }

        myfile.close();
      }

      else { cout << "Unable to open file"; }

    // now i want to try and edit a specific row (\n) and column (\t)


      return 0;
    }
```

Comment: First split the file by newlines to get rows and then split each of the rows on the tab to get column positions.

Comment: Unless you really need to work with raw text files, I'd suggest using XML.  There are many, good, free, lightweight XML libraries out there (e.g. pugixml).  Using XML would free you from having to deal with the low-level file-reading operations.

Comment: Hi Carlton, thanks for your reply. I'd like to do this with raw text files, as I'm interested if it's possible or not. I can't seem to find a solution to this "editing" problem online :/

Comment: Did you find any solution for this?